# SQL - convert date column to start and end dates

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to take a column of dates and create a new table that includes the start and end date of each continuous date range. For example (date format being mm/dd/yyyy):

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 01/02/2022 |
| 5 | 01/03/2022 |
| 5 | 01/04/2022 |
| 5 | 01/05/2022 |
| 6 | 01/02/2022 |
| 6 | 01/04/2022 |
| 6 | 01/05/2022 |

would create the following table:

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 01/02/2022 | 01/02/2022 |
| 5 | 01/03/2022 | 01/01/2022 |
| 6 | 01/02/2022 | 01/02/2022 |
| 6 | 01/04/2022 | 01/05/2022 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below

```
select id, min(cur_date) start, max(cur_date) as `end`
from (
  select *, countif(date_diff(next_date, cur_date, day) != 1) over win as grp
  from (
  select id, date, cur_date,
    ifnull(lead(cur_date) over(partition by id order by cur_date), cur_date) next_date
  from your_table, unnest([struct(parse_date('%m/%d/%Y', date) as cur_date)])
  )
  window win as (partition by id order by cur_date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
)
group by id, grp
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]